# Bash: write to specific column in CSV

Tags: linux, bash, unix, solaris

I am trying to write the contents of a .txt file to the "B" or second column in a CSV file.

```
awk '{$2 = $2"i"; print}' x.txt >> y.csv
```

I thought this would write the contents of `x.txt` to `y.csv` followed by the letter "i" in the second column. However, this code still writes to the 1st column.

Sample of x.txt:

```
hello
hellox
hello1
```

Sample output to y.csv:

*A Column*

```
hello i
hellox i
hello1 i
```

I want to have this content written to the B column. Preferably without the "i".

Any solution to this would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your field separator?

Comment: Could you show a sample input along with a sample output ?

Comment: It is comma delimited. I have added in sample input and output. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2 = $1} 1' file.csv
```

```
hello,hello
hellox,hellox
hello1,hello1
```

If you want literal `i` in 2nd column of output:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2 = "i"} 1' file.csv
```

```
hello,i
hellox,i
hello1,i
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This code duplicates the text in column A to column B, in the command output. I don't want the text in column A, I want it in column B of the .csv

Comment: So you want column `A` to be blank in output?

Comment: It is fine, I have used this and removed the text in column A. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're doing, the paste command would be easier and simpler