# How to Write A Second Column in Bash in an Existing txt file

Tags: bash, awk, xargs

I need to extract the ID name of a parent directory and put that in a tab-delimited text file. Then I need to extract names of the contents of that folder and put it in the same row as that ID name I first extracted. Essentially, Column 1 should list the directory name from parent, Column 2 should list the name first file in that directory, Column 3 should be the name of the next file, and so on and so forth.

/path/to/folder/ID/

```
pwd | xargs echo | awk -F "/" '{print $n; exit}' >> Text.txt
```

where 'n' is the location of the desired parent folder (in this case, ID). This works fine, and writes something like "ID001" to my Text.txt file.

I try the same little hack again, using my pwd as my input to xargs, listing out the contents of that folder, and writing the names to my Text.txt file:

```
pwd | xargs echo | awk -F "/" '{print $7; exit}' >> Text.txt | pwd | xargs echo | xargs ls | xargs echo >> Text.txt
```

But instead of

```
ID001 file1 file2
```

I get

```
file1 file2
ID001
```

Which is **mostly** to be expected, given the commands. I am confused as to why my file names are being appended to the *first* row and not to the *last* row. The only related article I could find was [this for writing a specific column to a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932569/bash-write-to-specific-column-in-csv), but it wasn't quite what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the point of `pwd | xargs echo`? Why not just `ls *`?. Your example can be reduced to just `echo 12 >> file | echo ab >> file`. You have a race condition, they are run in parallel - the content of the `file` can be anything composed of two streams.

Answer (score 2):

This `find` plus `awk` pipeline MAY be what you're trying to do:

```
$ ls tmp
a  b

$ find tmp -print | awk '{sub("^[^/]+/",""); printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep="\t"} END{print ""}'
tmp     a       b
```

YMMV if your file names contain tabs or newlines of course.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do that as part of multiple commands; for ease in understanding.

You can put the commands in a bash script.

Example scenario

```
$ pwd
/Users/pa357856/test/tmp/foo
$ ls
file1.txt   file2.txt
```

commands -

```
$ parentDIR=`pwd | xargs echo | awk -F "/" '{print $6}'`
$ filesList=`ls`
$ echo "$parentDIR" "$filesList" >> test.txt
```

Result -

```
$ cat test.txt 
foo file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 for some of the issues with that answer.